# Ionic - How to create an already existing application?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm really sorry if this question has already been asked.
I created an ionic app that I published on the Apple Store (and Play Store) some time ago.
I will would like to recreate this app using the latest version of ionic. Is it possible ?

Indeed, when I do a simple:

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios && ionic cordova platform add ios && ionic cordova prepare ios
```

Even if config.xml same as previous application, I cannot upgrade existing application on Apple Store. Can you explain to me how to do this?
Do you have the list of files I need to keep?

Thank you so much

PS: I prefer to recreate an application with ionic rather than trying to fix compilation problems that have nothing to do with my javascript code.

Comment: For Google Play store you just need to have Same `Keystore` File  and Password. 
for Apple Store: You need to have Same developer provision certificate you created in your `Xcode`. 
You can Create New ionic application (even from scratch).

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I will try again and I will contact you.